# Implementation of CRL in Glassfish 4.1

Tags: ssl, glassfish

I'm experimenting with an instance of Glassfish v4.1 installed in a VM trying to make mutal authentication work. Everything goes like a charm, except the CRL (certificate revocation list) part. I've searched through the whole Internet, but it seems nobody knows about managing CRL's in Glassfish v4.1. The only sites I found were [this](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/11/19/ssl-and-crl-checking-glassfish-v2#6) and [this](http://blogs.nologin.es/rickyepoderi/index.php?/archives/46-Certificate-Security-in-JavaEE-Demo-Setup.html). The first one refers to Glassfish v2/v3. None of them works.
Does anyone know if Glassfish v4.1 allows the implementation of CRL through a static file, like the article at the first link suggests? If so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out how to make it work. The first link I gave in my question pointed in the good direction, but it had an error. Actually, the property "crlFile" doesn't exist, at least not in Glassfish v3.0.1 ([Oracle GlassFish Server 3.0.1 Domain File Format Reference]). The right name is "crl-file" and it's an atribute of the element **ssl**.

```
<ssl crl-file="config/crl.pem" .... />
```

If you define this attribute, Glassfish enables the CRL checking, looking for the revoked certificates in the specified file. The solution is also valid for Glassfish v4.1.

I wish this may help someone at some moment.